# Use template to apply a function template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

If the following example were C++ it would contain non-sensical gibberish so I'll define the example to be written in pseudocode (and hence correct). It strongly hints at what I want to do in C++.

```
#include <vector>

template<class T>
void increment(T& x)
{
    ++x;
}

template<template<class> class F>
struct Apply
{
    template<class T>
    void operator()(std::vector<T>& v)
    {
        for (auto& x : v)
            F<T>(x);
    }
};

template<template<class> class F, class T>
void apply(F<T> f, std::vector<T>& v)
{
    for (auto& x : v)
        f(x);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};

    // apply increment function to v

    // maybe this?
    Apply<increment> a;
    a(v);

    // hmm... or this?
    apply(increment, v);
}
```

I don't know how to turn this into C++ such that:

1. `increment` is a function and not a function object.
2. The parameter of `increment` is either deduced or supplied by `Apply`/`apply`.
3. `Apply`/`apply` does not know about the name `increment`.

I can satisfy two out of the three but I'm not sure how to satisfy all three at once. The problem I run into is the apparent need for using a function template as a template template parameter which my compiler doesn't like. Still, it certainly seems possible to get this to work even if that particular route is off limits.

How can it be done?

**Edit:** I hate to change the problem but I didn't do a great job of trying to formally state requirements. Just pretend you're the author of apply but you're not the author of `increment`. You're stuck with `increment` as is.

Comment: What's wrong with a function object? Isn't std::transform exactly what you're looking for?

Comment: One thing that *isn't* in your requirements is "`apply` calls `increment` directly". If that indeed isn't a requirement, then a thin wrapper template class should do the trick. But based on your requirements, that seems to not be in the right spirit. (BTW, I understand that it's just an example, but `increment` shouldn't take `const T &`, as it modifies its parameter.)

Comment: BTW, depending on what you're looking for, a thin wrapper class could be a whole lot less intrusive if generic lambdas are allowed, but they're only available in C++14, and you tagged your question C++11.

Comment: @hvd C++14 is fair game but note the added statement of intent.

Comment: I was thinking exactly of the `[](auto &t) { increment(t); }` that MrT now already included in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up the type of a function and the function itself. 
Writing `Apply<increment>` in this case does not make sense since `increment` is the name of the function and not its type.
Furthermore you cannot use a templated function like this without specifying its templated types. But a workaround is to use a generic lambda instead.

Here is a working example

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::vector;

template<class T>
void increment(T& x)
{
    ++x;
}

template<class T>
void print(const T& t) {
    for(auto&& v : t)
        cout << v << " ";
    cout << std::endl;
}

template<typename T, typename F>
void apply(T& container, F function) {
    for(auto& v : container) {
        function(v);
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v{1,2,3};
    print(v);
    // To retrieve a function pointer you must specify the type
    apply(v, &increment<int>);
    print(v);
    // If your using c++14 you can use a generic lambda
    apply(v, [](auto& t) { increment(t); });
    print(v);
}
```

Comment: This is pretty good but it does require the person who knows the name `increment` to create the lambda. I suspect there just isn't a better solution if we demand `increment` is a function. And yes, the OP contains bogus C++, that's why it's "pseudocode". ;)

Comment: @hvd I meant to suggest it'd be preferable if the caller to `apply` didn't need to provide the lambda boilerplate, not that they could somehow not know about `increment`. I do think this answer is as close as C++ allows, and it's a perfectly good solution, so it's a bit silly but it just bugs me.

Comment: @Praxeolitic Well, there are macros, but they're probably worse than having the caller type out the lambda. :)

Answer (score 2):

Simple: Drop the whole lot.

```
template<class F, class T>
void apply(T& v, F f)
{
    for (auto& x : v)
         f(x);
}
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
    apply(v, [](int& i) { ++i; });
    auto a = [](std::vector<int>& v) {
         apply(v, [](int& i) { ++i; });
    };
    a(v);
}
```

You're just reinventing lambdas but worse. Functional programming in C++ is best done with function objects because regular functions have *shit* semantics, and we have language features explicitly for the purpose of making function objects easily, so use them.

As a commenter pointed out, this is also basically just `std::transform` but overly specific, and `std::transform` can also take a lambda.

Don't bother trying to functional with passing functions- it can't be done, at least not with a competitive code quality and volume. Use function objects and especially lambdas. This is literally what they're for.

Comment: Very nice, that does indeed satisfy all the requirements I stated, but the scenario I was thinking of is you're not the author of `increment` but you are the author of `apply`.

Comment: Is there any way to get this to work with the original increment?

Comment: @Puppy shouldn't it be possible to wrap them into function objects by using the `std::function` constructor?

Comment: @pqnet: `std::function` can only take function objects in the constructor.

Comment: @Puppy i meant it like this http://ideone.com/xOv4P8
From what I understand, pointers to (C) functions are indeed function objects

Comment: @pqnet: They are. But they cannot express templated functions or overload sets, which is what the OP wants. By the time you've gotten a function pointer, you've lost the desired behaviour.